# Вывод изображения из базы данных (BLOB поля)

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый вечер, форумчане, если у кого-то есть свободная минутка, буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Проблема заключается в том, что нужно вывести изображение из таблицы базы данных. Оно хранится в поле типа BLOB.

Я, глядя на примеры, написал некий скрипт, но в результате в браузер мне выводится вместо картинки из базы сообщение: «Изображение не может быть показано, так как содержит ошибки".
Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
   <?PHP
       header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
       require "PublicationManagementFunctions.php";

       $PublicationID = (int)$_GET['id'];

       OpenDBConnection();

       $SQLRequest = "SELECT * FROM ".TABLE_NAME." WHERE id=".$PublicationID."";

       $query = mysql_query($SQLRequest);
       CloseDBConnection();
       $row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC);
       echo $row['Image'];

   ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена. Суть заключалась в том, что подключение и отключение от базы выполнялось функциями из другого файла, который каким-то образом задавал неправильный контент-тайп, как только я отказался от подключения внешнего файла, все заработало правильно.

Добавляю код, может кому пригодится.

Скрипт для вывода изображения:

```
<?PHP

define('HOST',          'localhost'   );
define('DB_NAME',       'bagrijroman' );
define('TABLE_NAME',    'Publications');
define('USER_NAME',     'root'        );
define('PASSWORD',      ''            );

$PublicationID = (int)$_GET['id'];

$DataBaseHandle = mysql_connect(HOST, USER_NAME, PASSWORD) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME) or die (mysql_error());

$SQLRequest = "SELECT Image FROM ".TABLE_NAME." WHERE id=".$PublicationID."";

$query = mysql_query($SQLRequest) or die (mysql_error());

$row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC);

header('Content-type: image/jpeg; charset=utf-8');
echo $row['Image'];

mysql_close($DataBaseHandle);

?>
```